# Setting layout margins in pyqt

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

In Qt Designer I can set the margin of a VBox or HBox using the properties layout*Margin.

How can I do that in pyqt?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [QLayout.setContentsMargins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins):

```
# layout is a defined VBox or HBox
layout.setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on PyQt5. Method is the same, but whatever margin size I set has no effect at all.